# Cant set keyboard layout to wanted

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a program and I need to change input language to **english** if it isn't.

I use `LoadKeyboardLayout()` and `ActivateKeyboardLayout()` but it doesen't change the input language. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
    int Functions::KeyPush(char Index)
    {
        LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", KLF_ACTIVATE);

        ActivateKeyboardLayout(HKL_PREV, KLF_SETFORPROCESS);

        keybd_event(
        Index,
        Index,
        KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0,
        0);

        keybd_event(
        Index,
        Index,
        KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
        0);

        return GetAsyncKeyState(Index);
    }
```

Comment: You've changed the keyboard layout for your program.  Not the one you are sending keys to.  And no, you can't.

Comment: Oh... And i thought it would do the trick

Comment: @HansPassant: JUst out of interest, how does the little "keyboard layout" thingy that runs in the lower right corner of the typical Windows desktop work (assuming multiple keyboard layouts are enabled)? It appears to change the layout for all of the system...

Comment: I think sending the `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` message to the target window should work (assuming that it passes it through to `DefWindowProc`), although I have never tried this.